# JavaScript ES6 error using Velocity.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6, velocity.js

I try to use Velocity.js to do an menu button animation. The code worked well using jQuery but now I'm trying to do it using JavaScript ES6 only and I got an error.

My HTML content is this one :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Hamburger 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <hc-hamburger role="button">
        <a class="McButton" data="hamburger-menu">
            <b></b>
            <b></b>
            <b></b>
        </a>
    </hc-hamburger>

    <script src="velocity.min.js"></script>
    <script src="hamburger.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And my JavaScript content :

```
'use strict';

class HCHamburger extends HTMLElement {

    get menuButton() {
        if (!this._menuButton) {
            this._menuButton = this.querySelector("[data=hamburger-menu]");
        }

        return this._menuButton;
    }

    get bar() {
        if (!this._bar) {
            this._bar = this.querySelectorAll('b');
        }

        return this._bar;
    }

    attachedCallback() {
        this.menuButton.addEventListener('click', _ => {
            this.menuButton.classList.toggle("active");
      let McBar1 = this.bar[0];
      let McBar2 = this.bar[1];
      let McBar3 = this.bar[2];
      if (this.menuButton.classList.contains("active")) {
        McBar1.velocity({ top: "50%" }, {duration: 200, easing: "swing"});
        McBar3.velocity({ top: "50%" }, {duration: 200, easing: "swing"})
              .velocity({rotateZ:"90deg"}, {duration: 800, delay: 200, easing: [500,20] });
        this.menuButton.velocity({rotateZ:"135deg"}, {duration: 800, delay: 200, easing: [500,20] });
      } else {
        this.menuButton.velocity("reverse");
        McBar3.velocity({rotateZ:"0deg"}, {duration: 800, easing: [500,20] })
              .velocity({ top: "100%" }, {duration: 200, easing: "swing"});
        McBar1.velocity("reverse", {delay: 800});
      }
        });
    }
}

document.registerElement('hc-hamburger', HCHamburger);
```

When I click on my button I have this error : `Uncaught TypeError: McBar1.velocity is not a function`

As I said before this code worked with jQuery with a classic selector :

```
var McBar1 = $('b:nth-child(1)');
```

I think I have an issue when I get my McBar1 content because when I log it I juste have `<b></b>` and no the entire object...

Comment: ES6 does not magically make `querySelector` return a jQuery selection with a `.velocity` method. You still have to use jQuery to use that plugin!

Comment: Thank's for the answer. What is exactly returned by a jQuery selection ? Is there a way to achieve the same with pure JavaScript ?

Comment: The `$` function returns a jQuery instance, basically an object consisting of the selected elements and inheriting from the prototype that contains all of jQuerys utility methods, including the plugin ones. Of course it's possible to do the same without the library, given that the library is implemented in pure JS.

Comment: Ok thank's for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use jQuery to get the selection, querySelector is not enough.